# Child forms in VB.Net are sharing controls and conflicting

Tags: vb.net, conflict

I have a form that can spawn a child form, something like:

```
Private Sub RunBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RunBtn.Click
  Dim myChildForm As New form2()
  myChildForm.Show()
End Sub
```

I want to be able to launch multiple children.  Unfortunately, I seem to be getting conflicts within the controls of the children.  One button will run the other child's control, etc.  They also seem to think that their class-level variables are accessible to each other.  Private Shared variables like the following are conflicting (one form thinks it's seeing the other form's "mp3file" variable as their own):

```
Public Class form2
  Private Shared mp3file As MemoryStream
  ....
End Class
```

How do I spawn children forms that keep their controls and data separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Private Shared is shared across all instances of that class

```
Private Shared mp3file As MemoryStream
```

Simply remove the Shared attribute